# cakephp milesj uploader plugin: image is not uploading to destination directory

Tags: php, file-upload, cakephp-2.3, uploader

I'm using `cakephp uploader 4.3.1` plugin from `milesj.me`. I installed it using the `composer` its working properly.

Now the problem is when i upload an image one entry is added to the database with image path but i couldn't find the image in the destination folder.

the `Model->save` function is executing successfully.

I'm using `cakephp 2x`

**EDIT**

if i dont give destination directory the files will be uploaded to `/files/uploads` directory and i can find the images there!!!!!!!!!!

but when i give destination as `/img/uploads` i couldn't find.

**Model Code**
`CustomImage.php`

```php
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CustomImage extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'CustomImage';

public $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'upload_image' => array(
            'uploadDir' => '/img/uploads/',
            'finalPath' => '/img/uploads/',
            'dbColumn'  => 'path',
            'maxNameLength' => 30,
            'overwrite' => true,
            'stopSave'  => true,
            'allowEmpty'    => false,
            'transforms' => array(
                array('method' => 'resize', 'width' => 240, 'dbColumn' => 'photo_thumb'))
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
        'upload_image' => array(
            'extension' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
            'required'  => true
        )
    )
);
}
?>
```

**Controller Code**
`MotionMakerController.php`

```php
class MotionMakerController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
public $uses = array('CustomImage');

public function index()
{

}

public function add() {

    if ($this->CustomImage->save($this->request->data, true)) {
        echo "success";
    }
}

}
```

**View Code**
`add.ctp`

```php
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('CustomImage', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('upload_image', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

?>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a global variable and replace it with "/img/uploads/".
Ex :

> define('UPLOAD_DIR', WWW_ROOT . '/img/uploads');